# How Can I validate the JSON body of an API call in a separate method

Tags: rest-assured

**Trying to validate some JSON values outside of the first method. What would be the best way to do that in the second method ?**

```
@When("^User sends API request with (.*) and no qualifiers and an State Code entry level T1.3$")
public void user_sends_API_request_with_no_qualifiers_and_an_entry_level_T(String path) {
        response =
                given()
                        .auth().oauth2(DomaniRx_RestAssuredOAuth2.access_token_code)
                        .queryParam("PhamacyID","12345")
                        .queryParam("Customer Set Type ID", "CustomerSetTypeValue")
                        .queryParam("PharmacyListIDShortName","Value")
                        .queryParam("DateFilled","04/17/2022")
                        .get(defaultURL+path)
                        .then()
                        .statusCode(200)
                        .extract().response();
    }
 
@Then("^The Pharmacy ID in the response should match the (\\d+) in the request T1.3$")
public void the_Pharmacy_ID_in_the_response_should_match_the_in_the_request_T(String PharmacyID) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the `best` way, but I think one way to achieve that is put `response` is an instance variable, then you can access it from other method in same class.

If you want to share `response` outside class, then use class (static) variable

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your response body to a variable like the below:
Then you can make assertions easily on the other methods. You can define a ResponseModel according to your response. Its name can be changed. it's up to you.

```
 private ResponseModel response;
```

.

```
  response =
            given()
                    .auth().oauth2(DomaniRx_RestAssuredOAuth2.access_token_code)
                    .queryParam("PhamacyID","12345")
                    .queryParam("Customer Set Type ID", "CustomerSetTypeValue")
                    .queryParam("PharmacyListIDShortName","Value")
                    .queryParam("DateFilled","04/17/2022")
                    .get(defaultURL+path)
                    .then()
                    .statusCode(200)
                    .extract().response()
                    .jsonPath().getObject(".", ResponseModel .class);
```

Comment: does the ResponseModel has to be created in a different class ? it is not allowing me to create a variable in the same class. Hmm

Comment: yes, it should be in a different class that defines the response. I am using https://app.quicktype.io/ for creating the model. paste your response to the input on the left at the site. and select the options you want in the language section. it creates the model for you.